# Beautifulsoup to get values after </b>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

how can I extract the following using beautifulsoup

**Sunni (Traditional), All prayers including formal jum'a, Indonesian And  +61 2 9591 1593**

```
<div class="normalLink"><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0><tr><td rowspan="3"><img src="http://www.salatomatic.com/images/spacer.gif" width="7" border="0"></td><td></td><td rowspan="3"><img src="http://www.salatomatic.com/images/spacer.gif" width="10" border="0"></td></tr><tr><td><img src="http://www.salatomatic.com/images/spacer.gif" width="100" height="7"></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">

<b>Denomination:</b> Sunni (Traditional)<br>
<b>Demographics:</b> Predominantly Indonesian<br>
<b>Prayers:</b> All prayers including formal jum'a</br>
<b>Language of services:</b> Indonesian<br>
<b>Imam:</b> Unknown<br>
<b>Director/President:</b> Aly Zakaria<br>
<b>Phone:</b> +61 2 9591 1593<br>
<b>Website:</b> <a href='http://www.salatomatic.com/code/fn_web.php?id=5313' target=new>Click here</a> to visit website<br>
<b>Email:</b> <a href='http://www.salatomatic.com/de.php?id=5313'>Click here</a> to send email<br>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

so far I can only get the beginning of the br

**CODE**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()                                                                     soup1 content1 = urllib2.urlopen(currenturl).read()                                                                                                                       
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content1)                                                                                
div  = soup1.find('div', {'class':'normalLink'})
b = div.find('b')
print b
```

Comment: THIS question is different! seriously

Comment: In how far? You should elaborate on why you think the answers there don't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help..

```
info_list = soup.get_text().split('\n')

for i in info_list:
    print i  

Denomination: Sunni (Traditional)
Demographics: Predominantly Indonesian
Prayers: All prayers including formal jum a
Language of services: Indonesian
Imam: Unknown
Director/President: Aly Zakaria
Phone: +61 2 9591 1593
Website: Click here to visit website
Email: Click here to send email
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get each one seperatly

Comment: See my edit. Make it into a list, via the split method, splitting on newlines.